# Setting selenium to use custom profile, but it keeps opening with default

Tags: python, macos, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use python and selenium to automate some tasks in firefox. When I download a file, that pop up comes up asking if you want to open or save, and a check box for do this every time with this kind of file. I have found that check box does not work unless you install the add on Web Page Fixer. I have that installed normally, but when I use python + selenium it uses a profile with no add ons.

The internet has instructed me to create another profile by closing Firefox, opening /Applications/Utilities, then typing the command:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p
```

I then create a new profile that I will use with selenium. I set the name and change the folder name. The profile name is "PTI_Auto_Profile". The folder path displays as follows:

```
/users/User/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/Selenium/
```

When I am done. I click 'Start Firefox', and the following error appears on my terminal screen.

```
2013-04-11 11:57:30.422 firefox-bin[2248:707] invalid drawable
conf-room:~ User$ 2013-04-11 11:58:00.350 firefox-bin[2251:303] invalid drawable
```

I've tried the following to no success.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/Selenium/"))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

No error, default user.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.expanduser("~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/Selenium/"))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

No error, default user.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv/xls")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Error:
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
    NameError: name 'getcwd' is not defined

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

p.s. I am using mac os x 10.8.2, python 2.7, firefox 20

**SOLUTION PROVIDED BY Corey Goldberg.** This should work for all excel versions.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/vnd.ms-excel'))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: what about trying:    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Error: fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd()) NameError:
>   name 'getcwd' is not defined

`getcwd()` is not defined.  So I assume you want the `getcwd` from the `os` module:

- http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

add: `import os` , and then invoke with `os.getcwd()`.

or you could just add the import for this function:
`from os import getcwd`

your example with the proper imports included:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv/xls')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: Thank you! I discovered that the last part of the bottom most preference is MIME type. by replacing 'text/csv/xls' with 'application/vnd.ms-excel' I succeeded in downloading the excel file without the popup. Word on the net is it works for all excel file versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code has no effect on my browser. I still see that popup. I work on Win 7 - 64 bit and python 2.7; could you please help me?

Answer (score 17):

I did the following:

[image: Open Profile Directory]

Or:

Linux: `ls -d /home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/` to see user profile directories

Mac: `ls -d ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/*`

Output:

```
/home/jmunsch/.mozilla/firefox/xfoyzfsb.default/
/home/jmunsch/.mozilla/firefox/yxjwk1py.default/
```

**To load a custom user profile I ran through creating a profile in firefox and then did the following with the python selenium webdriver code:**

```
def setUp(self):
    self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/jmunsch/.mozilla/firefox/yxjwk1py.default')
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(self.profile)
```

System Info:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg_resources;pkg_resources.get_distribution("selenium").version

jmunsch@NE-522:~/Desktop/work$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 26.0
```

## also note

@Corey's answer to manually set a profile

All of the configurables can be found under `about:config`:

`profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)`

Comment: Found a link how to make as **selenium** profile for Firefox: https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/

Comment: This works on python3.5,Ubuntu,FF48. manually setting a profile in the code does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You should add this:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
    "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml")
```

It does work!