# Selenium: page displayed differently

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I lanuch firefox with the below URL (do not run it, it is blacklisted, I use it just for a  security test). Here is the simple code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js")
```

But I did not get what I want. I mean, when I run this URL by typing it myself on Firefox, i get this page: 
[image]

But when I launch Firefox with the above URL, I rather get this page:

[image]

How can I get the same result as on picture 1 with my code ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is controlled by the `browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled` Firefox preference. Changing it in `about:config` inside the Firefox browser reproduces the behavior you are describing: if it is turned on - Firefox would warn you about the site [being in the malware-detected block list](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?client=Firefox&hl=en-US&site=http://addonrock.ru), if it is off - you would see Firefox not loading the page at all.

And, FYI, this is that "Block reported attack sites" checkbox in the Security preferences:
[image: firefox security prefences]

Setting Firefox preferences through the `FirefoxProfile` should help:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.safebrowsing.enabled', True)
profile.set_preference('browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled', True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js")
```

You can also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23330140/771848), get the path to the user profile and pass it to the `FirefoxProfile` constructor.

Personally, I cannot make this work neither through setting specific preferences, nor by passing the existing profile. I suspect this could be reported as an issue in [the `selenium` bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list).

---

If you want to test whether a web-site is "flagged" as a dangerous to use, you can make a request to the google safebrowsing through their [API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) and the [python client](https://github.com/juliensobrier/google-safe-browsing-lookup-python) (API key can be generated [here](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/key_signup?csw=1)):

```
>>> key = 'your own key'
>>> from safebrowsinglookup import SafebrowsinglookupClient
>>> client = SafebrowsinglookupClient(key)

>>> client.lookup('http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js')
{'http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js': 'malware'}

>>> client.lookup('http://google.com')
{'http://google.com': 'ok'}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot and a lot, Alexander. You have been of a great help to me. I wish I could help you back one day too. Best regards kind and intelligent Man.