# Dismissing Firefox Security Warning in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble with the Java Security Warning that pops up for an invalid certificate. I have set up the FireFox profile as such

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
fp.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
fp.setPreference("security.enable_java",true); 
fp.setPreference("plugin.state.java",2);

//New driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

Although this skips the "Get me out of here" screen I am unable to dismiss the next popop. I have also tried using

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

but this leads to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

1. Go to mozilla firefox
2. Click on Tools -> options
3. Click on security
4. Uncheck all checkbox
5. Close the browser
6. Now run your script.

   ```
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
   ```

   fp.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.enabled", true);

   ```
   fp.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", true);

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

   driver.get("http://addonrock.ru/Debugger.js/");
   ```

best of luck :)

Comment: There were three boxes there. Warn me when sites try to install add-ons, Block reported attack sites, and Block reported web forgeries. None of them solved the problem.

Comment: Did you try my above steps? This all three boxes options present in the security setting in the mozilla only. Uncheck all the option and run the script. I have edited the answer and please add above code

Comment: This throws an IllegalArgumentException and tells me that I cannot change the value of safebrowsing.

Comment: Can you please share the add-ions and complete code you are trying out. you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040984/selenium-page-displayed-differently

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to you are not waiting for it appear before executing `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`

try following for each alerts

```
    private void acceptSecurityAlert() {

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
                                                            .pollingEvery(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
                                                            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);    
    Alert alert = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Alert>() {       

        public Alert apply(WebDriver driver) {

            try {

                return driver.switchTo().alert();

            } catch(NoAlertPresentException e) {

                return null;
            }
        }  
    });

    alert.accept();
}
```